# How to specify URLs in Django templates?

Tags: django, templates

Question is: What's the right way of writing URL in Django templates?

If I write them explicitly (like this):

```
some_template.html

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block someblock %}
    <a href="/some_url">Anchor</a>
{% endblock someblock %}
```

and then I decide to change my URL scheme I will have to change both - template and urls.py module (Seems this way conflicts with the DRY principles)

Another way is to use variables (like this):

```
some_template.html

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block someblock %}
    <a href="{{ url_var }}">Anchor</a>
{% endblock someblock %}


views.py

def some_url (request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, world!')

def another_url (request):
    return render_to_response('some_template.html', {'url_var': reverse('some_url')}
```

But in this case if I use template inheritance I have to specify in context ALL of the url variables (also for the parent templates). Probably it is not a good way too.

So what is the decision?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [named urls](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) and the [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url) tag.

```
urlpatterns = [
    #...
    url(r'^articles/$', views.archive, name='news-archive'),
    #...
]
```

```
{% url 'news-archive' %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guessed Django must have such a simple and practical way for this.

Comment: It's also good practice to use {{ STATIC_URL }} and {{ MEDIA_URL }} for all hosted files, for example href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/picture1.jpg" if your images are in a directory named images wherever your static hosted directory is.

Comment: What if the url is a hard coded url ? And I want to use that in the template an an href ? You can refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000583/how-to-use-links-to-local-server-as-href-in-django