# How to use links to local server as href in Django?

Tags: django

I want to have links that are clickable . That link is a path in a server.

**Example:**

file:///I:/IT/Install/Winrar/

SO far I have my view code:

```
def installables_available(request):
    install_path = r'I:/IT/Install/'
    list_setup = os.listdir(install_path)
    full_path = [os.path.join(install_path, item) for item in list_setup]
    return render(request, 'generic/installables.html', {'full_path': full_path})
```

And the html looks like:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>All Installables</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Below are all setups available</h1>
        {% for name in full_path %}
            <ul>
                <li><a href={{name}}> {{name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}

    <hr>
    <p>Thanks for visiting my site.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I do get the page showing links but , If I click them, they don't do anything. But hovering on them shows the correct path i.e e.g file:///I:/IT/Install/Winrar/.

[image]

Comment: Is the browser on a computer that has access to these paths directly? It should be obvious that this won't work across the internet.

Comment: @DanielRoseman..You are right..this is in intranet....i just want some kind of action to happen when I click on the hrefs...May be they can open the folder..or if it is a file...it was download or may be start executing the exe file...bottom line...if its a intranet link, what can we do?

Comment: I think that you might be missing quotation marks around `href` attribute. So try to change one line in your code from `<li><a href={{name}}> {{name}}</a></li>` to `<li><a href="{{name}}"> {{name}}</a></li>`